# seek does not work with in memory file

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-3.6

I have Django REST and my endpoint accept POST with attachemtn.

```
    if serializer.is_valid():
        instance = UploadedFile.objects.create(
            file=serializer.validated_data['file'],
            username=self.request.user.get_username(),
        )
```

Then I put file to the function. And repeatedly loop read this in-memory file.

```
for pair in daterange(start_date, end_date):
    bkk_start_datetime = mom_datetime.datetime.combine(pair, mom_datetime.time(0, 0))
    bkk_end_datetime = mom_datetime.datetime.combine(pair + timedelta(days=1), mom_datetime.time(0, 0))

    ans_dict = {
        "bkk_start_datetime": bkk_start_datetime,
        "bkk_end_datetime": bkk_end_datetime,
        "pin_values": pin_values_from_file(instance, bkk_start_datetime, bkk_end_datetime)
    }
    ans.append(ans_dict)
```

This function has problem because file does not seek to the first location.
 Although I put `.seek(0)`

```
def pin_values_from_file(instance: object, start_date: datetime, end_date: datetime):
    csv_file = io.StringIO(instance.file.read().decode('utf-16'))
    csv_file.seek(0)    # Seek the first line again. Otherwise next day will be zero all
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, dialect='excel-tab')
    count = 0
    holder = AwardHolder()
    logger.info(f"pin_values_from_file receive {start_date}, {end_date}")
```

How to let it re-read in-memory file?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the memory version. Think about it: you create the memory file in the function, so it will always be at offset 0.

What will **not** be at offset 0 is `instance.file`. This is an instance of [`FieldFile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#filefield-and-fieldfile) and as per docs:

> FieldFile.open(mode=’rb’)
>
> Opens or reopens the file associated with this instance in the specified mode. Unlike the standard Python open() method, it doesn’t return a file descriptor.
>
> Since the underlying file is opened implicitly when accessing it, it may be unnecessary to call this method except to reset the pointer to the underlying file or to change the mode.

So while you cannot use seek, as it is unimplemented, you can reopen it:

```
f = instance.file.open(mode='rt')
csv_file = io.StringIO(f.read().decode('utf-16'))
```

Comment: I am trying to understand your messages

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I got the error `io.UnsupportedOperation: seek` I believe it raises this because my file is not a file on the disk it is a file from `request` and does not save to storage yet. Then I decided to create new class and store all the value in there and now I can re-read them